# How to center text without using a preexisting Word style using the officer package in R

Tags: r, ms-word, centering, officer

I am struggling to find a way to center text in a Word document using the officer package in R.

I have to use a specific Word template so do not want to rely on the preexisting Word style = "centered".

Using fpar(ftext(...)) I am able to adjust many things about the text but simply centering text is proving difficult. ftext does not seem to accept the property text.align. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: there is an example here: https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/paragraphs-chunks.html#fpar for pptx and for docx

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidGohel! Much appreciated!